# Bigquery - Analytics Export - Userid and Goals

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Looking at the BigQuery Export Schema (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) I can't find the columns referring to the userid and to the Goals.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you post this to the Google Analytics Premium support team for specific questions about your data, since you already have paid access to support.

https://enterprise.google.com/supportcenter/managecases
http://www.google.ro/analytics/premium/contact.html

Answer (score 0):

Goals are not exported to bigquery you have to re do them in bigquery. 
If the goal triggers on a event you should get the number of events from bigquery.

Remember that events can trigger unlimited times during a session but goals only can be triggered once per session.